# Authenticate requests in expressjs

Tags: javascript, express

I made an express js backend which executes a couple of GET and POST requests I would like to call from a react web app.

This works perfectly fine. The only problem I would like to solve is to give a sort of “authentication” to the requests, ensuring they are all legitimate.

I would like to avoid a user inspecting my requests through inspect elements, and later sending them through his own tools.

I thought I could generate a code on the react web app, send it through a query parameter and then verify the code in the backend. Only problem with this would be that a good enough user could read the code understanding the code generation process, despite potential obfuscation.

Thus, what would be the best approach?

Thanks

Comment: ***I would like to avoid a user inspecting my requests through inspect elements, and later sending them through his own tools.*** This is basically impossible.  Anything that can be done in a browser can be viewed by a hacker and repeated in their own tools.  And, this can all be done without even looking at your code, they can just look at the network traffic coming out of the browser.  Repeat after me: "There are no secrets in a browser", "There are no secrets in a browser".

Comment: Anything that requires security or secrets must be implemented on the server and then access to that API can be protected/verified with some account credential login.  You can then monitor usage on that account to see if they are doing something excessive and shut-down or limit the account if so.